# Build jar with Docker using gradle->gradlew

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile, gradlew

I'm new with Docker, I'm study and learning....So.....sorry for the bad code. I'm trying to generate the jar when I'm building my docker image; I would like to use a basic image of openjdk and use gradlew (gradle-wrapper) to do the clean and build but I'm having problems with gradlew.

Currently I have this code:

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.2
LABEL authors="ivanh"
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./ .
RUN ./gradlew clean build
ENTRYPOINT ["ls"]
EXPOSE 8001
```

when I run `docker build -t citas .` I have this problem

```
------
 > [4/4] RUN ./gradlew clean build:
0.390
0.390 xargs is not available
0.390
------
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   3 |     WORKDIR /app
   4 |     COPY ./ .
   5 | >>> RUN ./gradlew clean build
   6 |     ENTRYPOINT ["ls"]
   7 |     EXPOSE 8001
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c ./gradlew clean build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I'm search about that and ask to the IA. I found that one solution is change openjdk image and another solution is add this command `RUN microdnf install findutils` but with the last solutions the time is very slow while download and install the util.

I'm confused because I think the purpose of gradle-wrapper is run commands without have gradle installed. Can someone clarify this for me ? If the only solution is change the openjdk image, can you recomend me one?

Comment: Using the wrapper would still download Gradle, so instead of that, use Gradle base image that already has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `gradle:jdk17` base image, which is based on OpenJDK 17.0.10.

```
FROM gradle:jdk17

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./gradlew clean build

ENTRYPOINT [ "ls" ]
```

Assuming a test project layout like this:

```
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   ├── java
│       │   │   └── org
│       │   │       └── example
│       │   │           └── App.java
│       │   └── resources
│       └── test
│           ├── java
│           │   └── org
│           │       └── example
│           │           └── AppTest.java
│           └── resources
├── Dockerfile
├── gradle
│   ├── libs.versions.toml
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

[image]